# Function call with class as argument vs class method: Preference or coding style?

Tags: oop

I have recently started to learn Julia and came across the coding convention of using `functionname!` (appended exclamation mark), if the function changes one of its arguments on its call. Now, coming from python, I used to generally take it for granted, that functions that change an object should be implemented as class methods, whereas functions that use an object as a constant can be also implemented as usual function calls. Let me demonstrate in an example:

Take a usual list assignment in python and some possible function calls with it:

```
>>> l = [2,1,3]
>>> sorted(l)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> l.sort()
>>> l
[1, 2, 3]
```

To me it is intuitively clear - from my perspective and experience - that the first function call does *not* change the list itself, but returns a copy of the list, which has been sorted. On the other hand, the class method call *does* change the list itself, hopefully not even necessarily utilizing extra memory etc.

Now in Julia, these two different approaches of sorting a list are implemented as `sort(l)`, which does *not* change the list itself, but returns a copy of the sorted list, and `sort!(l)` which changes the list itself and does not create a copy.

Now my question is: when writing my own code in Julia, is it now considered self-evident to adapt my coding style to the convention of the Base library or is this just pure preference? The question, of course, does not apply solely to Julia, as I assume every object oriented programming languange has a similar "problem", as classes can use their methods in order to achieve a change in the class itself or an "external" function call.

Additionally, what are the advantages or disadvantages of using one of those styles over the other, or does it depend on the function itself, whether it is useful to implement one or the other?

Comment: Writing your code in a convention commonly used in a language makes it easier for others to read and understand